# How to migrate mysql database from Ubintu to Windows?

Tags: sql, database, mysql, rdbms

I have a database which I need to migrate from Ubuntu to Windows system. I created sql files but some data gets corrupted. Is there any different approach or solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it works but with some quirks. MySQL uses the same fileformats across platforms so all you need is to share the data directory. One problem is that the data directory need to have mysql as owner and group in ubuntu. And Windows is case-insensitive and Linux is case-sensitive so keep all names uniform: either the whole name lowercase or uppercase but do not mix them.

in your my.ini (in Windows it's located somewhere like C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1. It's the main configuration file for MySQL) file, you should have this line:

datadir="C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.1/Data/" for example

change it in both Windows and Linux Ubuntu to point to one single physical folder (on a partition with a file system which Windows could recognize). It will work. File formats are identical.

Whether you boot from Ubuntu, or Windows 7, it won't matter, 2 different builds of MySQL will be looking for data in the same place. Once data is modified in Windows environment, you boot up from Ubuntu and the data is there, modified.